# SSIS Package Timeout Issues

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, ssis

I have an automated daily import where I am running a SQL Server Integration package programmatically.  The error message it reports is "Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding."  I believe this is the same message reported when ADO.NET commands timeout.  I have looked at the documentation for Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Package, and I see no obvious way to check and/or raise the timeout value.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Most SSIS packages use a number of connections during their execution.  I suggest turning loggin on and usign that to try and track down which operation is timing out.  That then should tell you which connection manager is timing out.

Answer (score 0):

The timeout is most likely set on the database server.

And you should probably work on increasing your query performance before having that increased.